# fog-aws gem uses http or https calls?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, fog

AWS exposes both APIs(Http and HTTPS). [fog-aws](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws) gem uses http or https calls? I am not able to find it anywhere in it's description.

Comment: https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb#L10

Comment: @Зелёный, please, don't give anwers as a comments, use `Your Answer` textarea for that. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexeyShein i never post link only answer. it's just a point for the OP. if you want, post it as an answer, i upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [default is HTTPS](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb#L10), as pointed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499118/fog-aws-gem-uses-http-or-https-calls?noredirect=1#comment52857951_32499118).

Comment: Yeah, I think you could choose to use http, but we try to use https wherever available.